# Размытые линии при визуализации

Tags: c#, wpf

Сейчас пытаюсь написать тестовое приложение, используя **WPF** и визуализацию графических данных через визуальный уровень.

Имею обычный Window со `StackPanel` в которой находится объект отнаследованный от `FrameworkElement`:

```
<custom:CustomVisualFrameworkElement UseLayoutRounding="True" />
```

Вот **код элемента**:

```
public class CustomVisualFrameworkElement : FrameworkElement
{
    VisualCollection theVisuals;

    public CustomVisualFrameworkElement()
    {
        theVisuals = new VisualCollection(this);
        theVisuals.Add(AddOne());
        theVisuals.Add(AddTwo());
    }

    private Visual AddOne()
    {
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Rect(0, 0, 70, 100), 10, 10);
        }
        return drawingVisual;
    }

    private Visual AddTwo()
    {
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        { 
            drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Rect(100, 0, 70, 100), 10, 10);
        }
        return drawingVisual;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return theVisuals.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= theVisuals. Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ();
        }
        return theVisuals[index];
    }
}
```

После запуска приложения у нарисованных прямоугольников размытые линии, хотя свойство `UseLayoutRounding` я выставил в `TRUE` и, если я правильно понял MSDN, выставления этого свойства должно быть достаточно.

Сейчас даже мыслей как это исправить нет. Есть у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: "хотя свойство UseLayoutRounding я выставил в TRUE" установи в `FALSE`

Comment: Попробовал - отображает также.

Comment: `UseLayoutRounding` необходимо использовать, начиная от окна. Проблема в том, что оно устанавливает целыми локальные координаты контрола в родительском контроле. Если при этом у родительского контрола самого нецелые координаты, эффекта никакого не будет. // Поскольку значение наследуется, по идее достаточно прописать только в окне.

Comment: Т. е. нужно еще и в самом Window выставить UseLayoutRounding?

Comment: Тоже не помогло. Самое интересное, что в редакторе все отображается нормально, но при запуске появляется размытие.

Comment: Почитайте тут, может найдете решение вашей проблемы: [откуда «мыло» в WPF и как с ним бороться](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216833/). Так как используется рисование DrawContext, то возможно одним UseLayoutRounding не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ [вот  в этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256125/forcing-drawingcontext-lines-to-snap-to-pixel-boundaries).

Как только заменил DrawingVisual на

```
public class MyDrawingVisual : DrawingVisual
{
    public MyDrawingVisual()
    {
        VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
    }
}
```

начало визуализироваться нормально.

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В `App.xaml.cs`

```
public static void Main()
{ 
    FrameworkElement.UseLayoutRoundingProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window),
                                                              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                                                                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
    ...
}
```

Comment: По идее, `true` вместо `false`?

Comment: по идее `false` это отключение размытия.

Comment: Правда? Тогда `false`. (Я думал, что `false` — это субпиксельные координаты и размытие.)

Comment: Нет, в MSDN сказано: "true if layout rounding is applied; otherwise, false. The default is false". То есть округление до ближайшего целого происходит при true, в противном случае вы будете получать нецелые координаты, то есть размытие. так что VladD прав.

Comment: К теме про размытие есть статья на хабре: [Откуда «мыло» в WPF и как с ним бороться](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216833/)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик к сожалению тоже не сработало. Пойду читать хабр, если найду способ, напишу здесь.